# Removing backslashes in the numbers sequence

Tags: java, regex

What regular expression can get a number sequence from the input string, contains backslashes and not a numbers, for example -

`"12\34a56ss7890"`

I need to -

```
1234567890
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example:

```
String a ="1\2sas";
String b ="1\\2sas";

System.out.println(a.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z\\\\]",""));
System.out.println(b.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z\\\\]",""));
```

gives output:

```
1X
12
```

where X is not a X but a little rectangle - a symbol which is shown when the text showing control does not know how to draw it, a so called non printable character.

It is because in String a the "\2" part obviously tries to be interpreted as a single escaped sign "\u0002"- similar to "\n" "\t" - you can see this in debugger (i tried it using NetBeans)

Since the first argument of a replaceAll method is passed to [Pattern.compile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)) it needs to be [escaped twice](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) as opposed to String literal (like b).

So if the String "12\34a56ss7890" looks like this on screen you have printed it out like this:

```
System.out.println("12\\34a56ss7890");
```

which is solved in the second example.

However if the literal is given as "12\34a56ss7890" then I *think* you can't handle it with a *single* regexp, because if the backslash is followed by a number it gets interpreted as as \u0000 -\u0009 so the best I can think of is a very ugly solution:

```
str.replaceAll("\u0000","0").replaceAll("\u0001","1") ... .replaceAll("\u0009","9").replaceAll("[^\\d]")
```

the first then replacements (\u0000-\u0009) might be rewritten as a for loop to make it look elegant.

+1 for an EXCELLENT question :)

EDIT:
actually if a backslash is followed by more than one number they all get interpreted as a single sign - up to three numbers after a backslash, the fourth number will be treated as a single number.

Therefore, my solution is not generally correct, but could be extended to be. I would recommend Robin's solution below as it is far more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

If we assume you have this in a String. You could do something like:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

This will replace all non digit Characters from your String.

Comment: I always forget about the capital variant instead of using **[^]** . nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

```
str.replaceAll("[^\d]", "");
```

**bootnote: im not a java developer, but the regex itself should be correct**

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for adding another Answer but this is needed because this won't fit to an Comment.

I think this is because of the \34. If I do call `System.out.print("12\34a56ss7890");` I will get the following output `12a56ss7890`. This is because the \34 will be escaped. This is an Issue in Java. You can fix this by first calling this Method on your InputStream:

```
private InputStreamReader replaceBackSlashes() throws Exception {

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(new File("PATH TO A FILE");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(fis, "UTF-8");
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        String nextLine = in.nextLine().replace("\", "");
        out.write(nextLine.getBytes());
        out.write("\n".getBytes());
    }

    return new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
}
```

BTW: Sorry for my Edit, but there was a little Mistake in the Code.

After calling this Method you will convert your InputStream to a String and the call this on the String:

```
string = string.replaceAll("\\D", "");
```

This should hopefully work now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
   String num;
   String str =" 12\34a56ss7890";
   str= str.replace("\34", "34");
   String regex = "[\\d]+";

   Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
    while (matcher.find( ))
    {
    num = matcher.group(); 
    System.out.print(num);                 
    }
    replace \34 by 34 and match the rest using regular expression.
```

Answer (score 1):

User a regular exxpression.

```
String numvber;
String str =" 12\34a56ss7890";
str= str.replace("\34", "34");
String regex = "[\\d]+";//match only digits.

Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile( regex ).matcher( str);
while (matcher.find( ))
{
num = matcher.group(); 
System.out.print(num);                 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The character `\34` is an octal number in the string `12\34a56ss7890`, so you could use:

```
str.replaceAll("\034", "34").replaceAll("\\D", "")
```